# Communication between two rails applicarions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Rails applications. One is like web store and the other is like delivery service app.

I want to create something like this:
User goes to web store, buys some stuff. If this person wants these items to be delivered to his house, he fills the order form and the delivery service app receives information from web store with the delivery address.

Can anyone tell me what would be the best way to do that? If possible, maybe give some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current thinking is that usually the best way for two web apps to communicate is using [RESTful interfaces](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) that pass data in JSON format.  Rails is built to support this [by default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) alongside HTML based interfaces for users using web browsers.  With this architecture, other applications can use the web app in a manner very similar to users using browsers but optimized for data interchange.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to expose your application as a web service.
There is a great chapter about how to do this in the rails recipes book.

Another good option would be to use JSON. From your store website you can post JSON to the service app, and in the service app you can read the JSON as a parameter hash.

Comment: Page 100 of the pirated book has "syndicate your site with rss" and page 93 talks about adding web services, but instead shows how to render xml instead of the default json. (this has nothing to do with what is commonly known as web services - the soap specification)

Comment: Searching the web my first thought was to parse .xml data from web store application and than read these .xml data in my delivery service. Would it work, and how could I read the data, given from .xml?

Comment: @Michaerr I wanted to know if I am going in the right direction? From my web store application I parse .json data with format.json { render json: @forms }
 I receive json data like this `[{"address":"aaa","created_at":"2013-04-24T15:40:57Z","id":1,"item_id":2,"number":0.0,"updated_at":"2013-04-24T15:40:57Z","user_id":null}]`

How can I now get this data to be shown at my delivery app?

Comment: @Karlis, there are a few options, you can use ActiveResource (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) here is a youtube about how to use it (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sF-m3P-Mrm8), this means you would basically route some of the data to an external app, or you can just use a simple Rest client, here (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) is a good example of how to achieve it. Once you posted, in your receiving application the data appears as a hash and you can access it through params[]

Answer (score 0):

If a customer bought a product, will he choose not to deliver? The features of the two apps are so dependent that I see no reason you should have two.

If you plan to grow the second app to a platform that accept lots of such delivering requests from several apps of yours and external owners, you can go further to turn the second app into a RESTful service.

If you don't have such plan, better to integrate them into one app.